# FutureBuilder in the build method, infinite loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, future

I am attempting to use a futurebuilder to get data out of a database and then display it on the screen once it is loaded in. I currently have my futurebuilder in the build method but it creates an infinite loop.

This is the contents of my build:

```
try {
      initUser();
      initRead();
      return Scaffold(
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child:  FutureBuilder(
              future: _read(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
              List<Widget> children;

              if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
                children = <Widget>[showImage()];
              } else {
                children = <Widget>[
                  _showCircularProgress(),
                ];
              }
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: children,
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return Container();
    }
```

How can I use this FutureBuilder to check when `_read()` has finished without getting this infinite loop? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424828/infinite-loop-on-using-futurebuilder-with-api-call

Comment: My reasoning to not consider this as the same, is that when I attempt to create the future variable and then have it initialize in the init method, my future builder never advances past the loading state as if it was never receiving a snapshot at all, would you have any idea on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I moved those there to test something, normally they are in the initstate. My fault!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line where you return your column is not within your `if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError)` line, try including it

so,

```
if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
   return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: showImage(),
            ),
          );
        }),
} else {
   return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children:  _showCircularProgress(),,
            ),
          );
        }),
}
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Sorry for the late response